# Silverlight Toolkit Expander Button Style/Icon

Tags: silverlight, toolkit, expander

I'm looking for an easy way to change the styling of the expander button in the Silverlight Toolkit Expander control. For example:

- Smaller or larger icon.
- Replace the icon with another one.
- Change the colours of the icon being used.

TIA

Craig

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is essentially the bread & butter of what Expression Blend is good for. In Blend you would just right-click your control and choose to edit a copy of the template. Then you would find the Toggle Button, and then edit THAT template.

Otherwise, you'll need to find the Control Template for the expander in your ToolkitStyles.xaml though it's much easier with Expression Blend though. You'll find Templates for all four directions an expander and go.

A quick solution search for;

```
<Style TargetType="toolkit:Expander" x:Key="DefaultExpanderStyle">
```

Should produce your default template you can either edit directly or make a copy of (just make sure to rename the Key name if you copy it) and that way you have all your States & Transitions etc already also. Remember your culprit will be the embedded ToggleButton inside the template for whichever direction expander you're wanting to edit.

Hope this helps.